# Stock value not updating after purchase with PayPal smart button

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, payment-gateway

I have a checkout page for each product where payments are carried out. I have done so that when one complete's a payment the stock value changes. I am doing this via ajax using the fetch-api to accomplish this. However, the code does not seem to work.

Here is my current code.
view_product.php:

```
    </div>

<?php
include 'pdo_connect.php';

$product_id = $_GET['product'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products Where id = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $product_id );
$stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $stock = $row['stock'];
        
        if ($stock > 0){
        echo 
        "<script>
        paypal.Buttons({

            style: {
                shape: 'rect',
                color: 'blue',
                layout: 'vertical',
                label: 'paypal',
                locale: 'en_CY'
            },
        
            createOrder: async function(data, actions) {
                let stock = (await fetch('get_current_stock.php')).json();
                let currentStock = stock['current'];
        
                // you may want to check for amoutTryingToOrder instead of 1
                if (currentStock < 1) {
                    alert('Out of stock, sorry :(');
                    return false;
                }
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: ". $row['paypal_price'] .",
                            currency: 'EUR'
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    //alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                    alert('Your payment has been processed!');
                    localStorage.clear();
                    window.location.href = 'http://localhost/YourLocalArtist/thankyou.php';
                    
        
                    const formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('amountOrdred', 1);
        
                    fetch('update_stock.php', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: formData
                    });
                })
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
      </script>";
    }
    else{
    echo   
    "<h1>OUT OF STOCK</h1>
    <script>render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>";
    }
   }
 ?>
```

get_current_stock.php:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  include 'pdo_connect.php';

  $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','', 'yourlocalartist-db');
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER by id ASC';
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

  while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $currentStock = $product['stock'];

  echo json_encode([
   'current' => $currentStock
   ]);
  }
?>
```

update_stock.php:

```
<?php

 $_POST['amountOrdered'];

?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like your update_stock.php file does nothing, this is the reason why your stock is not updating. You need to add some code that updates corresponding values in database after purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment mentions, your update_stock.php file does absolutely nothing--there are no statements in it, just a variable name.

Specifically, you will need PHP statements that run a SQL query with an 'UPDATE' statement if you want to make changes to existing rows in the database